# Memory warning causing zombies to be released in iOS7

Tags: ios, memory

I've been banging my head against the wall on this one.

I have an app that has a root view controller and two child view controllers. One of the children is a navigation controller. The other is a view with a bunch of buttons in it. When buttons are pressed on the menu, a corresponding view controller is instantiated and the navigation controller has its view controllers set to a single item array containing this new controller.

All of this works fine. The problem is that if I use the app for a bit and then simulate a memory warning it crashes trying to send a message to a zombie. The zombie is different every time but is always a view controller or subview of a view controller's view that has already been deallocated. For instance if I have my navigation controller set to A and then push B, then pop B I can break at B's dealloc and see that it is removed. Then if I simulate a warning I'll get a crash because something is trying to send a message to B.

Here is an example trace:

```
 0 CoreFoundation ___forwarding___
 1 CoreFoundation _CF_forwarding_prep_0
 2 UIKit +[UIViewController _traverseViewControllerHierarchyWithDelayedReleaseArray:block:]
 3 UIKit +[UIViewController _traverseViewControllerHierarchyWithDelayedRelease:]
 4 UIKit -[UIApplication _performMemoryWarning]
 5 UIKit -[UIApplication _receivedMemoryNotification]
 6 UIKit __43-[UIApplication setReceivesMemoryWarnings:]_block_invoke_2
 7 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_client_callout
 8 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_source_latch_and_call
 9 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_source_invoke
10 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
11 CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
12 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun
13 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific
14 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunInMode
15 GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal
16 GraphicsServices GSEventRun
17 UIKit UIApplicationMain
18 myapp main /Users/blahblahblah/main.m:18
19 libdyld.dylib start
```

The app delegates `applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning` is called but `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is not called on any of my view controllers before the crash.

There are no leaks and no warnings from analysis and I am following the rules for containment view controllers.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: Yes. In my case it was due to a dangling reference. I was registering a notification callback in a category so it was not getting unregistered during dealloc. The traceback was pretty useless.